# What Android app replicates the iPhone Siri (voice recognition) functionality?

Tags: applications, voice-command

The new [Siri](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/siri.html) app on the iPhone looks pretty intersting (at least from the videos).  Is there an application on Android that matches or improves on the same functionality?  Specifically, something that doesn't require the memorization of *robotic* voice commands?

I have tried [Vlingo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.vlingo.client&hl=en), but for many requests it just seems to perform a Google search which leaves you in a web browser without voice functionality.

Comment: Google Voice Search has come a LONG way since 2011 and has similar functionality (and sometimes) better then Siri now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing (at present) that can do all that Siri does.

Depending on your needs you might be able to get close.

Lifehacker had an article about your current alternatives: [How to Get a Siri-Like Personal Assistant on Your Android Phone for Free](http://lifehacker.com/5848973/how-to-get-a-personal-assistant-like-siri-on-your-android-phone-for-free)

To summarize: You'll need one of the following (or a combination):

- [Google Voice Actions for Android](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/)
- [Vlingo](http://www.vlingo.com/)
- [Edwin](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.neureau.edwin)
- [SpeakToIt Assistant](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speaktoit.assistant)

***Update***: [terryk2 points out Iris](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14676/what-android-app-replicates-the-iphone-siri-voice-recognition-functionality/14728#14728), currently in alpha testing, which is by the developers' own admission a direct response to Siri.

Comment: Google's looking into a real natural language search app: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Google-X-Working-on-Siri-Alternative-for-Natural-Language-Searches-240702.shtml Not out yet though

Comment: Any updates in the intervening two years? There are phones like Moto X now, that can listen continuously.

Answer (score 8):

While still in alpha, it may be worth checking out [Iris](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dexetra.iris&feature=search_result).  It's got a limited set of Siri's functionality, but it looks like it could be interesting to watch it grow.

Answer (score 2):

That would be [Google Search](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch), which also has voice command abilities. Although I am not sure how intuitive the commands can be given, compared to Siri.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say [Vlingo](http://www.vlingo.com/) is probably the closest but doesn't have the contextual power that Siri does but it's very close.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called [Skyvi](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bluetornadosf.smartypants) in the android market. Initially I used IRIS, but it was quite buggy. This is comparatively better in my opinion. It's humorous as well.